# Error de terminal mac con c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, terminal, macos

Estoy iniciándome en la programación y estoy aprendiendo *C#*, con sistema operativo de *Mac*. Utilizo *Visual Studio* para *C#* y cuando quiero ver el código en el terminal tengo errores en los caracteres como esto:

> ?Cu?l es tu nombre?

En vez de esto:

> ¿Cuál es tu nombre?

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: echa un vistazo a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005405/how-can-i-turn-on-special-ascii-characters-in-visual-studio.

Comment: gracias Iria, mi inglés no es perfecto pero creo que no me ayuda a solucionarlo....

Comment: tu problema se debe a que tienes caracteres especiales, es decir, no están en inglés, generalmente hay un código para cada uno de ellos, para que salga, tienes que averiguar cuál es el código que tienes que poner en lugar de á, é, í, ó, ú o ñ en cada caso